# Share home WiFi connection temporarily

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

I have a WiFi router at home, and sometimes I have guests which need to access to the Internet via my WiFi. It's quite troubling, though, to give them the master password to my access point; I only want to give them temporary access to my private network.

What is the best way to share my private WiFi connection with others without a temporary password change? Disabling requiring password and enabling list of privileged MAC addresses (MAC filtering) isn't an ideal solution.

Comment: Does the router allow a guest network (surprisingly many do). If you want to use a local solution as suggested by Antony, which OS's do you run?

Comment: I have both *Windows 7* and *Linux Debian*. Solutions for both operating systems are welcome. 
+1 for *guest network*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest way: Use your laptop with WiFi. Run as administrator:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork key=somepassword 
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

To get the SSID:

```
netsh wlan show hostednetwork
```

You can `netsh wlan stop hostednetwork` after that to stop any time.

Comment: +1 for brief and useful answer. Now just hope that the OP uses windows.

Comment: Please familiarize yourself [with our formatting](http://superuser.com/editing-help).

Comment: ++ for fast and simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, if the driver of your WLAN card does not support hosted network, Connectify is a way around.